# Javafx: confirmation before exit (X button)

Tags: javafx

I need show alert confirmation before application closes (X pressed Button)

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    ...
    primaryStage.setOnHiding(event -> {
        System.out.println("hidding");
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, Lang.getString("exit_confirmation"));
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

        if (result.isPresent() && result.get() != ButtonType.OK) {
            return;
            //don't close stage
        }
    });
}
```

But anyway `primaryStage` is closed. How can i code in order to exit application only if `ButtonType.OK` is pressed? Sorry for my english

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's always better to google your problem first as you can find a better explanation, but here's your answer

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
         //your code goes here


         //this line cancel the close request
         event.consume();
    }
});
```